# Enable scroll on the axis of D3 chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have a simple stacked bar chart :
The code is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVVLXY).

I would like to have scroll-bar on the axis but as you can see in the link the scroll appears for the div container with the help of CSS.
But i need something like this [chart with scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSRhc.png)!

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
       <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.goquery.min.js"></script>
       <style>
        .axis path,
        .axis line {
          fill: none;
          stroke: #BDBDBD;
        }
       .axis text {
         font-family: 'Open Sans regular', 'Open Sans';
         font-size: 13px;
       }
       .y.axis{
         direction: ltr;
       }
      .grid .tick {
        stroke: lightgrey;
        opacity: 0.7;
      }
     .grid path {
       stroke-width: 0;
     }
     .rect {
       stroke: lightgrey;
       fill-opacity: 0.6;
     }
     .wrapperDiv {
     Width: 984px;
     height:  35px;
     border: thin solid black;
     #margin-top: 36px;
     #margin-bottom: 48px;
     #margin-right: 20px;
     #margin-left: 0px;
     }
     .divChart {
     float:left;
     font-size:13px;
     color : #424242;
     font-family: 'Open Sans regular', 'Open Sans';
     #border: thin solid white;
     margin-top: -0px;
     #margin-bottom: 48px;
     #margin-right: 150px;
     margin-left: 50px;
     #background-color: lightgrey;
     width: 984px;
     height: 500px;
     #padding: 25px;
     border: thin solid navy;
     #margin: 25px;
     #max-height:500px;
     overflow-y:scroll;
     direction: rtl;
     }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="divChart" id="wrapper-chart">
     <div id ="chartID" ></div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script><script>  
  <script>       
     var dataset = [{"key":"Completion","values":[{"name":"Module 1","value":0},{"name":"Module 2","value":0},{"name":"Module 3","value":0},{"name":"Module 4","value":0},{"name":"Module 5","value":0},{"name":"Module 6","value":0},{"name":"Module 7","value":0},{"name":"Module 8","value":0.56},{"name":"Module 9","value":13.24},{"name":"Module 10","value":12.66}]},{"key":"NonCompletion","values":[{"name":"Module 1","value":100},{"name":"Module 2","value":100},{"name":"Module 3","value":100},{"name":"Module 4","value":100},{"name":"Module 5","value":100},{"name":"Module 6","value":100},{"name":"Module 7","value":100},{"name":"Module 8","value":99.44},{"name":"Module 9","value":86.76},{"name":"Module 10","value":87.34}]}]; 

     function intChart(chartID, dataset) {

     var margins = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 120};
     var width = 880 - margins.left -margins.right;
     var height =  5250- margins.top - margins.bottom;
     var old_width = width,old_height= height;
     var module_fixed = 80;

     height = Math.floor((dataset[0].values.length * height)/module_fixed)

     var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1,.1)
     var y = d3.scale.linear().rangeRound([height, 0], .1);
     var series = dataset.map(function(d) {
         return d.key;
     });

     dataset = dataset.map(function(d) {
     return d.values.map(function(o, i) {
        // Structure it so that your numeric
        // axis (the stacked amount) is y
        return {
            y: o.value,
            x: o.name
        };
     });
     });
     var stack = d3.layout.stack();
     stack(dataset);
     var dataset = dataset.map(function(
     group) {
     return group.map(function(d) {
        // Invert the x and y values, and y0 becomes x0
        return {
            x: d.y,
            y: d.x,
            x0: d.y0
        };
     });
     });

     var xMax = d3.max(dataset, function(
     group) {
     return d3.max(group, function(d) {
        return d.x + d.x0;
     });
     });
     var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
     .domain([0, xMax])
     .range([0, width]);
     var moduleName = dataset[0]
     .map(function(d) {
        return d.y;
     });

     var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .domain(moduleName)
     .rangeRoundBands([height,0]); 

     var svg = d3.select('#chartID')
     .append('svg')
     .attr("width", width + margins.left +
        margins.right)
     .attr("height", height + margins.top +
        margins.bottom)
     .append('g')
     .attr('transform', 'translate(60,' + margins.top +
        ')');
     var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(xScale)
     .orient('bottom')
     .ticks(2)
     .tickSize(0)
     .tickPadding(20)
     .tickFormat(function(d) {
        return d + "%";
     });


     var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
     .scale(yScale)
     .orient('left')
     .tickSize(0);
     var colours = d3.scale.ordinal().range(
     ["#8bc34a", "#ff8a65"]);

     var groups = svg.selectAll('g')
     .data(dataset)
     .enter()
     .append('g').attr('class', 'stacked')
     .style('fill', function(d, i) {
        return colours(i);
     });

     var rects = groups.selectAll(
        'stackedBar')
     .data(function(d, i) {
        return d;
     })
     .enter()
     .append('rect')
     .attr('class', 'stackedBar')
     .attr('x', function(d) {
        return xScale(d.x0);
     })
     .attr('y', function(d, i) {
        return yScale(d.y);
     })

     .attr('height', 48)
     .attr('width', 0)

     rects.transition()
     .delay(function(d, i) {
        return i * 50;
     })
     .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.x0);
     })
     .attr("width", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
     })
     .duration(3000);
     //Added
     x.domain(dataset.map(function(d) {
     return d.value;
     }));
     y.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(
     d) {
     return d.name;
     })]);

     svg.append('g')
     .attr('class', 'x axis')
     .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' +height + ')')
     .call(xAxis)
     .append("text")  
     .attr("transform", "rotate(360)")
     .attr("y",10)
     .attr("x", 140)
     .attr("dy", ".30em")
     .text("Percentage of Students");

     svg.append('g')
     .attr('class', 'y axis')
     .call(yAxis)
     .selectAll("text")
     .style("text-anchor", "end")
     .attr("dx", "-.5em")
     .attr("dy", ".15em")
     .attr("y", "-")
     .attr("opacity", 1)
     .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(-40)"
     })


     // Draw Y-axis grid lines
        svg.selectAll("line.y")
          .data(y.ticks(2))
          .enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "y")
          .attr("x1", 0)
          .attr("x2", 450)
          .attr("y1", y)
          .attr("y2", y)
          .style("stroke", "#ccc"); 
     }  

     $(document).ready(function(){

     intChart("chartID", dataset);

     });


  </script>
```

Would appreciate any help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this can be done using D3 only. If you want to use CSS, you need to fix the position of the x-axis. You can add a separate DIV and SVG container for the X axis (these are not scrollable), and the rest of the chart in another.

I modified you code to do this [see here](http://codepen.io/ahmohamed/pen/mJJqyL). Please note that you code needs a lot of cleaning, as there are several non-functional parts that makes it really confusing.

The modifications are as follows:

### HTML

Added a new DIV (`xaxis`)

```
<div  id="wrapper-chart">
  <div class="divChart" id="chartID"></div>
  <div id="xaxis"></div>  
</div>
```

### CSS

Added styling for the new div (same as `divChart` but without the scrolling)

```
#xaxis {
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #424242;
  font-family: 'Open Sans regular', 'Open Sans';
  width: 984px;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

### JS

A new SVG container for the x-axis. Notice the `height` attribute.

```
var xaxis_svg = d3.select('#xaxis')
  .append('svg')
  .attr("width", width + margins.left + margins.right)
  .attr("height", margins.bottom)
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(60,0)');
```

Append the x-axis to the container.

```
  xaxis_svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'x axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + 0 + ')')
    .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("y", 10)
    .attr("x", 140)
    .attr("dy", ".30em")
    .text("Percentage of Students");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But  the only reason why i did not use CSS is , if suppose i have more values in x-axis and i need scroll for the same , then it would not be a good UI. I think we need to use jquery/ js but am not aware how on scroll both axis labels n corresponding rects scroll.